# Using my own attributes with Subsonic SimpleRepository

Tags: .net, subsonic

I have been looking for an ORM of late and SubSonic with its SimpleRepository appears to be the solution I'm looking for.

Is there a way to use my own attributes or ones from `System.ComponentModel` to drive some of the generation of the SQL? I want to keep my model/domain objects clean of third-party stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend that but this can be done.

Create your own attributes that match SubSonics attributes (like `OrmIgnore` instead of `SubSonicIgnore`, the still have to Implement `SubSonic.SqlGeneration.Schema.IClassMappingAttribute` or `SubSonic.SqlGeneration.Schema.IPropertyMappingAttribute` or `SubSonic.SqlGeneration.Schema.IRelationMappingAttribute`

Look at this code from SubSonic.Core\Extensions\Object.cs to get an idea what's happening

```
    public static ITable ToSchemaTable(this Type type, IDataProvider provider)
    {

        ...

        var typeAttributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IClassMappingAttribute), false);

        foreach (IClassMappingAttribute attr in typeAttributes)
        {
            if (attr.Accept(result))
            {
                attr.Apply(result);
            }
        }

        ...

        // Now work with attributes
        foreach (IPropertyMappingAttribute attr in attributes.Where(x => x is IPropertyMappingAttribute))
        {
            if (attr.Accept(column))
            {
                attr.Apply(column);
            }
        }

        ....

    }
```

your Apply implementation should modify the schema to do what you want.
Like this one (from SubSonicDefaultSettingAttribute):

```
    public void Apply(IColumn column)
    {
        column.DefaultSetting = DefaultSetting;
    }
```

You should check out the SubSonic source and mark every custom attribute as obsolete

```
[Obsolete("Use OrmIgnore instead", true)]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class SubSonicIgnoreAttribute : Attribute { }
```

There are some direct references to the attributes (that don't use the interface) that you will need to fix.

And you will have to look for string references

```
    private static bool ColumnIsIgnored(object[] attributes)
    {
        foreach (var att in attributes)
        {
            if (att.ToString().Equals("SubSonic.SqlGeneration.Schema.SubSonicIgnoreAttribute"))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

with

```
    private static bool ColumnIsIgnored(object[] attributes)
    {
        foreach (var att in attributes)
        {
            if (att.ToString().EndsWith("OrmIgnoreAttribute"))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```